# Installing mmenu in Wordpress via npm error

Tags: wordpress, mmenu

I've been trying to install the mmenu.js package (not a WP plugin) on Wordpress. My site is already setup for npm so I've downloaded the package and updated my package.json and gulpfile and everything is compiling nicely into assets/styles/styles.css and assets/scripts/scripts.js and these are properly wp_enqueue_script-ed. I'm using a simple test page without the header and footer includes, just the wp_head() and wp_footer() functions to provide the scripts and stylesheets. Everything appears to be working correctly with the installation except I get a single error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: o is not a function
    at e.backButton (mmenu.js:2:27071)
    at e.value (mmenu.js:2:6157)
    at new e (mmenu.js:2:3093)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (mmenu-test/:228:34)
```

At least the error message shows that mmenu is firing and the script is being read, which is a start. I just hope someone else out there has been through this and understands the problem and how to fix it.

Thanks,
Len

Comment: This appears to be a load order issue. Since the files are getting compiled/minified, I'm going to assume that `o` references a mmenu function that is being called in another JS file. Do you have a custom scripts file that you are calling a mmenu function?

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for this response. When you mentioned compiling/minifing, it sparked my growing suspicion that, given the o reference, the error might somehow be the result of the minimizing(??). I'm so new to node/npm workflow and I wanted to try an unminimized version of the js, so switched from using the node_module code and reconfigured to use CDN links for the js and css. It worked! So, thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I'm guessing the compiling process compiled in a way that put the code in the "wrong" order. If you use the node_modules compiled stuff, just remember to put anything you do last in the dependencies or enqueue it after the node stuff.